# unable to store data from $request to mysql using Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, json, angular, laravel

I am passing a POST request with 3 variables

```
Id (Randomly Generated), 
Name (Specified)
Capacity (Specified)
```

from an Angular Service post. These are in the payload of the POST, and also visible in `$request` variable in the Laravel resource controller method "store()".

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $servers = new Server();
    return $request->getContent(); 
}
```

Here in Chrome's developer tool>network>POST request>on preview I get this

```
[{name: "bakar", capacity: 50, id: 8012}]
0: {name: "bakar", capacity: 50, id: 8012}
```

but when I use

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $servers = new Server();
    $data = $request->getContent();
    $servers->id = $data->id;
    $servers->name = $data->name;
    $servers->capacity = $data->capacity;
    $servers->save();
}
```

In the above method I got an error exception stating:

> " Trying to get property of non-object "

How can I solve this?

Comment: Can you try to dd($request) to find out what is in it?

Comment: [{name: "bakar", capacity: 50, id: 8012}] 0: {name: "bakar", capacity: 50, id: 8012}    this was in the request!

Comment: do I seperately dd($request) ?

Comment: can you try with $data[0]->id, $data[0]->name, $data[0]->capacity

Comment: after dd($request) I got a complete list related to attribute, when I apply getContent() method it will return a body of the request to me which is

Comment: [{name: "bakar", capacity: 50, id: 8012}]
0: {name: "bakar", capacity: 50, id: 8012}

this

Comment: Naveen, It is not working same error now, 
" Trying to get property of non-object "

Comment: In that case you need to debug and see what is _actually_ in $data. Just because you see something in the request in Chrome, that's useful, but if the PHP isn't doing what you expect, then you need to check what it has actually received. Possibly it isn't expecting JSON data in the request, for instance. Maybe it's a simple string still and you need to decode it into an object. a `var_dump()` should help you, if you don't have a debugger available. If you _are_ receiving info into $data correctly, then my answer below should work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your JSON sample, `$data` should contain an array, which then contains a single object at its first index.

Therefore you cannot do e.g. `$data->id` because that's assuming that $data has a property called $id...it doesn't, the *object at its first index* does.

So simply `$data[0]->id` would allow you to access that index, and then access the $id property of the object at that index. Of course if your request contained multiple items in the array, you might need to use a loop to go through them all and get the values. It depends what you're expecting and what you intended to do with it.

Or, it may be the case that your PHP is correct, and it's your client which is sending the data in the wrong format. It's not clear what the desired outcome actually is.

---

**Edit:**

Since it appears that `$data` is still a JSON string when it arrives in your store() function, you need to decode it. So first write

```
$data = json_decode($request->getContent());
```

(instead of `$data = $request->getContent();`) and then proceed as above.

Complete sample:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $servers = new Server();
    $data = json_decode($request->getContent());
    $servers->id = $data[0]->id;
    $servers->name = $data[0]->name;
    $servers->capacity = $data[0]->capacity;
    $servers->save();
}
```

Comment: it is JSON which is being return and it is not saving, It is giving me same error after using $data[0]->id,

Comment: @Dr.Bakar see my comment on the main thread...if you're seeing that problem then you need to debug some more because it's not clear what your situation actually is in terms of the data.

Comment: sir when I return $request->getContent(), it will return
[{name: "bakar", capacity: 50, id: 8012}]
0: {name: "bakar", capacity: 50, id: 8012}
capacity: 50
id: 8012
name: "bakar"

Comment: or simple [(name:"bakar",capacity:50,id:8012)]

Comment: error=>>>    at HandleExceptions->handleError(8, 'Trying to get property of non-object', 'D:\\node\\MEAN\\laravel\\app\\Http\\Controllers\\ServerController.php', 57, array('request' => object(Request), 'servers' => object(server), 'data' => '[ { "name": "bakar", "capacity": 50, "id": 8012 }]'))

Comment: @Dr.Bakar To me it looks like you are probably seeing a string of JSON. What type does `var_dump()` say that `$data` is? If it's a string (rather than array) then you need to [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) it into a PHP array before you can use it. Or maybe your request needs to set the content-type to JSON and possibly Laravel will then decode it automatically - I don't know Laravel specifically (I just know about PHP and JSON) so I don't know if it has that feature or not.

Comment: array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#182 (3) { ["name"]=> string(5) "bakar" ["capacity"]=> int(50) ["id"]=> int(8012) } }  <<== this is what i get after var_dump applying on $data = json_decode($request->getContent());

Comment: @Dr.Bakar ok good. Seems it was a JSON string, then, and now you've decoded it. So...now you've decoded it into an array you can use `$data[0]->id` after that line in order to get your ID. See updated answer above.

Comment: @Dr.Bakar No problem. I hoped you learned something about how to interpret a JSON string and understand its structure :-)

Comment: yes, very much, and credit goes to you ;) for listening to me patiently and then helping me out!